# Using .find to identify the row number

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that searches a column in two sheets and identifies duplicates. The code works and a msgbox tells me the loan number that is duplicated but I want to modify the code to tell me the row number so I can then delete the row based on the vbYesNoCancel result. I just don't know how to identify the row number. I need to know what I can put in the part of the code that says Selection.EntireRow.Delete.

```
Sub Delete_Closed_Loans()
Dim cell As Range, rngData As Range, rngMain As Range, LoanFound As Range
Dim MSG1 As String

With Sheets("Data")
    Set rngData = .Range("C11:C" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
With Sheets("Main")
    Set rngMain = .Range("A8:A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With

For Each cell In rngMain
Set LoanFound = rngData.Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If LoanFound Is Nothing Then
    MSG1 = MsgBox(cell.Value & " " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & " loan not found, delete?", vbYesNoCancel)
If MSG1 = vbYes Then
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ElseIf MSG1 = vbNo Then
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `LoanFound.Row` gives you the row number.

Comment: I got an error when adding that to the code, error is Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: That means that `LoanFound` is `Nothing` so that specific loan was not found.

Comment: The code does return 3 loans that are duplicates and gives me the loan number from and with the offset it gives me the value in the next column over which is the borrower's name. But it does not give me the row number. The code should give me the row number for each duplicate it finds. This is what I tried, I put this code right below the if loanfound is nothing part  MSG1 = MsgBox("Row #" & LoanFound.Row & " " & cell.Value & " " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & " loan not found, delete?", vbYesNoCancel). Should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your revised code. It'll be easier to see than code in a comment.

Comment: You are looping in `Main` and you are searching in `Data`. What are you trying to do when a value is found (delete the row in `Data` or in `Main`, or nothing)? What are you trying to do when a value is not found (delete the row in `Main`, or nothing)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but I refactored your code so it's more readable.

EDIT: Added validation if the mainCell is null

EDIT2: Code had a flaw because I was deleting the rows starting from the top. Now it's correct (begins from bottom to top). Please update yours.

```
Public Sub Delete_Closed_Loans()
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''MAIN''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Set reference to main sheet
    Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
    Set mainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
    
    ' Get last row in main sheet column A
    Dim mainLastRow As Long
    mainLastRow = mainSheet.Range("A" & mainSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set data range
    Dim mainRange As Range
    Set mainRange = mainSheet.Range("A8:A" & mainLastRow)
    
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''DATA''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Set reference to data sheet
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    ' Get last row in data sheet column C
    Dim dataLastRow As Long
    dataLastRow = dataSheet.Range("C" & dataSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Set data range
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = dataSheet.Range("C11:C" & dataLastRow)
    
    
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''LOOKUP''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    
    ' Set first for in main range
    Dim mainFirstRow As Long
    mainFirstRow = 8
    
    ' Search for main loans in data range
    Dim mainCell As Range
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = mainLastRow To mainFirstRow Step -1
        
        ' Get cell position in range
        Dim cellPosition As Long
        cellPosition = counter - mainFirstRow + 1
        
        ' Assign cell from range
        Set mainCell = mainRange.Cells(cellPosition, 1)
        
        ' Search for main loan in data range
        Dim loanCell As Range
        Set loanCell = dataRange.Find(what:=mainCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        ' Check if loan was not found
        If loanCell Is Nothing And mainCell.Value <> vbNullString Then
            ' Ask user to delete loan
            Dim deleteLoan As Long
            deleteLoan = MsgBox(mainCell.Value & " " & mainCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & " loan not found, delete?", vbYesNoCancel)
            
            ' Delete loan in data sheet
            Select Case deleteLoan
            Case vbYes
                mainCell.EntireRow.Delete
            Case vbNo
                ' Do something?
            Case vbCancel
                ' Do something?
            End Select
            
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Give it a try and let me know if it works.

**PS. Backup your data before trying it!**

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer and also thank you for the way you broke up the pieces of the code. I actually can understand each process. Thank you very much for teaching me to fish :-)